# printf sendo duplicado depois do primeiro loop

Tags: c

Tenho esse programa e no primeiro loop do while ele roda normalmente, printa uma unica vez cada coisa, porem no segundo loop ele printa "Digite S para votar, N para ver a apuracao dos votos e sair." duas vezes antes de ler. Alguem sabe me dizer o por que?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {

    char resp;
    int presidente[15], governador[12], votop = 0, votog = 0, i = 0, x=2;



    while (x != 0) {

        printf ("Digite S para votar, N para ver a apuracao dos votos e sair. ");
        fflush(stdin);
        resp = getchar();

        if (resp == 's' || resp == 'S') {

            printf("\n\n\n Digite o numero para presidente: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf_s("%d", &votop);

            i = votop;

            presidente[i] = presidente[i] + 1;

            printf("\n\nAgora digite o numero para gorvernador: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf_s("%d", &votog);

            i = votog;

            governador[i] = governador[i] + 1;

            printf("\n\n\nObrigado por votar.\n\n\n");

        }
        if (resp == 'n' || resp == 'N') {
            x = 0;
        }
    }




    printf("\n\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o erro, mas eu tive que mudar algumas coisas para testar no ideone que não aceita o C11, e aproveitei e melhorei várias coisas para o código ficar mais legível: https://ideone.com/f3RzXt

Comment: A unica modificação que notei em relação ao problema foi um char antes do nome da variavel no getchar, mesmo adicionando o mesmo o erro ainda ocorre.

Comment: Não, eu só coloquei em outro lugar e mostrei que não acontece o erro.

Answer (score -1):

Entrada de dados em C com scanf é um assunto confuso. O uso de fflush(stdin) é polêmico, nem sempre funciona do jeito que a gente espera. Ao fazer a leitura de um caracter, ao invés de usar getchar é mais garantido usar `scanf(" %c", &ch);`, que garante que o caracter newline (corresponde ao ENTER ou RETURN do teclado) seja ignorado.

Abaixo uma versão do programa que funciona corretamente, testado no Linux e no Windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char resp;
  int presidente[15], governador[12], votop = 0, votog = 0, i = 0, x=2;

  while (x != 0)
  {
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Digite S para votar, N para ver a apuracao dos votos e sair: ");
    scanf(" %c", &resp); // <--- veja o espaço antes do %c

    if (resp == 's' || resp == 'S')
    {
      printf("\nDigite o numero para presidente: ");
      scanf("%d", &votop);

      i = votop;

      presidente[i] = presidente[i] + 1;

      printf("\nAgora digite o numero para gorvernador: ");
      scanf("%d", &votog);

      i = votog;

      governador[i] = governador[i] + 1;

      printf("\nObrigado por votar\n");
    }

    if (resp == 'n' || resp == 'N')
    {
      x = 0;
    }
  }

}
```

ADENDO:

Teste no Windows 10, compilado com Visual Studio 2005

```
D:\projects\misc
$ so339544.exe

Digite S para votar, N para ver a apuracao dos votos e sair: X

Digite S para votar, N para ver a apuracao dos votos e sair: X

Digite S para votar, N para ver a apuracao dos votos e sair: X

Digite S para votar, N para ver a apuracao dos votos e sair: N

D:\projects\misc
$ so339544.exe

Digite S para votar, N para ver a apuracao dos votos e sair: s

Digite o numero para presidente: 13

Agora digite o numero para gorvernador: 40

Obrigado por votar

Digite S para votar, N para ver a apuracao dos votos e sair: n

D:\projects\misc
$
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas quando uso o scanf do jeito que me disse o programa buga totalmente e começa a descer letras infinitamente na tela.